# Why is my iPhone phone app causing poor battery performance all of a sudden?

Tags: iphone, battery

I'm running iOS 16.5.1.  In the last couple of days, my normally battery-efficient phone has been running out of battery in less than 6 hours, even with Low Power mode enabled.  Today the battery usage showed the phone app having taken up 47% of the battery, even though I was only on the phone for less than a minute.

[image]
[image]

Also, the phone is physically hot to the touch, which never happened before, even when I was running low on battery.  Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot/repair my poor battery performance?  I have not installed any apps in the last several days.